# Symfony - render view of all users in a view

Tags: php, function, symfony

I returned 10 users in a view via this fucnion..

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $u = $this->get('u')->getUsersBy();

    return $this->render('@Templates/admin/users.html.twig',
        array('u' => $u)
    );

}
```

but I need to separate it and to return ALL users via second function, but  can't figure this part out.

Comment: We need more informations. What is the differences between this 10 users and the others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but typically when you want to return all data from your db, you're doing something like :

```
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YOUR/USER/ENTITY')->findAll();
    return $users;
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.